# How to get model binder to leave null strings as null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Sql Server database has some nullable nvarchar fields, and no nvarchar fields containing empty strings. I want to keep it this way, but the default MVC model binder seems to turn null strings into empty strings.

When a controller retrieves a null nvarchar database field, the null field turns into null string inside the controller, and from there the view renders them, say as blank text boxes. When the page is posted, the default model binder uses these blank text boxes to update the model, and the formerly null strings are changed to empty strings. When the data is updated back to the database, nulls are overwritten with empty strings.

What is the easiest way to get model binding to leave these nulls unchanged?

Comment: What's an SS database, SQL Server?  As a practical matter, you should be able to ignore the difference if you test for String.Empty or "" instead of null, since those two things will return true for null as well.

Comment: Yes, SS = Sql Server. Null and the empty string are not identical and you can't ignore the difference, either in T-SQL or in C#. In the past I had a painful experience in a project where blending of the two caused a lot of unexpected behaviors (bugs). For example if a programmer just tested (x == null) instead of using String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) on the C# side or (x IS NULL) instead of (x IS NULL OR LEN(x) = 0) in SQL the test will fail, apparently randomly, depending on whether the default value of null has been changed to the empty string or not.

Comment: I was bitten by this one again today. I missed decorating a class property with [Required], so my validator (xVal) did not notice the property becoming an empty string. The object containing this empty string property was then written into a database, where the NOT NULL constraint on the table field of course did nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer to follow through on this question. After working with it for a while I came to see this problem as part of the general concern of model integrity. For a while I had implemented a solution inside my update stored procedures to catch empty strings and turn them to nulls, along the lines of mikerennick's answer above. Later I wanted also to make sure fields were trimmed and I happened to move the application to NHibernate (and most of the stored procedures went away). In the end I embedded some POCO logic to trim and check for empty strings (from whatever source) in the setters as so:

```
public MyClass {
  private string _name;
  public string Name {
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value.TrimToNullIfEmpty(); }
  }
}

public static class StringExtensions {
  public static string TrimToNullIfEmpty(this string s) {
    string temp = (s ?? "").Trim();
    return temp.Length == 0 ? null : temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you are probably looking for something more sophisticated, but the default behavior of the ModelBinder is to convert empty form field values into the default value for the datatype of your model object property.  String properties become empty, int properties become 0, etc.

You can obviously create a validation scheme that will check for string.empty and convert to null prior to updating the DB.  For int form fields you will need to check for 0, and then convert to null.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I only care about strings becoming non-null, not integers or anything else. 

As for validation, I take care of most of that through class annotations and the xVal project. In this scheme, when a validation error is detected, a automatic RulesException is thrown that automatically turns into a validation error message. I don't want to create an exception that ends up on a page that in fact is due to the model binding process.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack I used a few months ago before I found the eden of stackoverflow. :) It's a pain, and doesn't scale well, but it works:

Basically, you override the binding inside of a partial linq object. If there's a value you know should always be null (but never legitimately empty) you can do the following. I used this for a string-based user id (SID).

```
partial void OnSubProcess_Owner_UserChanged()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SubProcess_Owner_User))
       this._SubProcess_Owner_User = null;
}
```

James

Answer (score 0):

The right answer might be to override the default Model binder to add this functionality yourself.

Maybe you could have a NullValueAttribute that you could apply to string properties to identify the null value. Then make empty string a null value.

I am experiencing the same problem at the moment and will probably resort to this